# My Polo wont start when it has been parked in the sun

Tags: starting, vw, polo

Everytime when I park my Polo 2004 model in the sun, it refuses to start or even when I have driven for a long distance. Despite the dashboard lighting up, the engine does not crank when I try to start it. I recently bought a brand new battery but I'm still experiencing the same problem. Just yesterday after church I had to ask someone to jump me and the engine roared to life.

When I park it in the shade its a completely different story.

I literally have to wait for it to cool down. What could be the problem?

Edit (from comments):

The dashboard does light up and everything else works perfectly well including the radio.

The engine does not crank when I start it. I recently bought a brand new battery but I'm still experiencing the same problem. Just yesterday after church I had to ask someone to jump me and the engine roared to life.

Comment: Could be a defective relay or coolant temperature sensor.  Have you had the engine codes read? If not, do so and update your question with any found.

Comment: Did you find out what it was? My Polo is having the same problem and it's driving my crazy. No-one has been able to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

If the car can easily be jump started but won't start on the key, even with a new battery, one of the most likely issues it point to is bad earths.

It could be that the earthing straps are corroded, damaged or even missing.  Remove each one in turn and clean up the contact points with a stiff wire brush or some emery paper and see if this alleviates the problem.

Comment: I thought that as well, but can you explain how this is effected by the car sitting in the sun?

Comment: No idea but if it was anything else like fuel vaporisation in the heat or a bad reading from a temperature sensor, jumping it wouldn’t help.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s like mine you’re having fuel vapour lock issues.
It’s relieved by taking the plastic cover off the engine, just tug to release, under there is a fuel rail, at the end is a blue cap, remove it.
Then there’s a little pressure valve, like on a tyre, just press and a bunch of air AND fuel will release. Should work then.